# xslt how to change the tag name of child node recursively

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, dita

I have my `xml` content in the below form where appendix can have any no. of sub children as well.

```
<topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="AppendixA-test.dita">
    <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="AppendixA-sub-test.dita"/>
  </topicref>
  <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="AppendixB-test.dita"/>
```

now I want my **output xml** to look like this:

```
<appendix href="AppendixA-test.dita">
      <topicref href="AppendixA-sub-test.dita"/>
    </appendix>
    <appendix href="AppendixB-test.dita"/>
```

Comment: An example is not enough: please explain the required logic in words.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- 
        Convert first-level <topicref> elements to <appendix> and copy the attributes,
        but ignore the @outputclass attribute
    -->
    <xsl:template match="topicref[contains(@outputclass, 'Dx:Appendix')][not(parent::topicref)]">
        <appendix>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='outputclass'] | node()"/>
        </appendix>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
        Copy all elements and attributes, except the @outputclass attribute
        (default copy template)
    -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='outputclass'] | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an XSLT-1.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- copy all nodes except those more specific -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- modify all "topicref" nodes except those more specific -->
  <xsl:template match="topicref">
    <xsl:element name="appendix">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@href" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- do not modify the names of "topicref" elements with "topicref" parents" -->
  <xsl:template match="topicref[parent::topicref]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@href" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You could make the 1st template `match="topicref[not(parent::topicref)]"` and eliminate the 2nd one. If that's the expected logic here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I tested it with two(instead of three) templates and the problem has been the copying of the `outputclass` attribute of the inner `topicref`. So one way or another I needed a second/third template... I also wondered about the expected structure but without further info this is as good as it gets.